# JSF commandButton giving 404 - /500.shtml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF commandButton, simply should submit a form,

```
<h:form  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="add"
    onclick="return validate('submitForm')"
    action="#{propertyBean.submit}"
    class="btn btn-green btn-lg arabic"
    rendered="#{propertyBean.isNew == true}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

the button is working okey on localhost but when I deploy the application on a server I get this error

> HTTP Status 404 - /500.shtml
>
> type Status report
>
> message /500.shtml
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

the action method is never called, as the backing methods prints a statement as its called.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is two-fold. A HTTP 500 error occurred (usually, because an exception was thrown), so the container needs to display a HTTP 500 error page which was in your case apparently registered as `/500.shtml`, but the container could in turn not find that file and hence the HTTP 404 error on that file.

In order to find out the problem causing the method not being invoked, you've 2 options:

1. Read the server logs to find the exception.
2. Register a valid HTTP 500 error page and let it print the stack trace.

Once having the real exception at hands, you can easily solve the underlying problem.

Comment: thanks @BalusC for your answer, apparently it was a server security option "mod_security", I found a suggestion online that it might be the cause, after contacting the host administration, they solved the problem